Sudden drop in temperature in Sun convective zone
In the solar temperature graph, why does the temperature drop suddenly in the convective zone? Is it because some energy is needed for ionisation?


The temperature gradient in the convection zone is basically the adiabatic temperature gradient - that is what defines the convection zone. The adiabatic temperature gradient can be written
$$\frac{dT}{dr} = -\left(1 - \gamma^{-1}\right)\frac{\mu}{k_B} \frac{GM(r)}{r^2}\ , $$
where $\gamma$ is the usual ratio of specific heats, $\mu$ is the mean particle mass and $M(r)$ is the mass within radius $r$.
In the convection zone $M(r) \simeq M_{\odot}$ and is roughly constant, but $r$ is of course increasing. $\mu$ is also roughly constant. The gas becomes less ionised so $\gamma$ gets a little smaller below the surface, but there are no major changes until you get to quite low temperatures ($10^5 > T > 10^4$ K - Baturin et al. 2021). Overall $dT/dr$ is almost constant, with the increasing $r$ meaning it becomes a little smaller in magnitude with increasing radius.
So what is going on? Well, the main effect is that you are just looking at a plot with a logarithmic scale on the y-axis. If you look instead at a solar model on a linear scale you can see that indeed $|dT/dr|$ slightly decreases with radius in the convection zone.
i.e. if $dT/dr$ is roughly constant, then $d \log T/dr = T^{-1}dT/dr$ and increases with decreasing $T$.

